# Autokey - how to set a phrase folder in a single order?

Tags: autokey

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't find it. I'm using Autokey in a rather simple setting - I have the default folder loaded with some phrases that I don't feel like typing out or finding and copy-pasting when I need them (for example, an auto-generated college account ID that I can't change). The folder has a hotkey to open, and from there I can hit a number button to paste any of the phrases in the folder.

The problem is, as I use the phrases, the program seems to shuffle them, putting the more used ones closer to the top. This is really annoying, as I'd rather know which ones correspond to which numbers and not have to read through every time to find them. However, I can't find a settings option in the gui, and I can't find it in the documentation either, which seems rather scattered. Does anyone know how I can change this?

currently running Kubuntu 20.04 if that makes a difference - I unintentionally installed the GTK version of Autokey, but from what I've read that shouldn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the GUI, you can disable autosorting of the pop up menu under:
Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Pop Up Menu